# WYSIHTML5 character counter Issue

Tags: jquery, wysihtml5

I have used WYSIHTML5 text editor in my project.. I need to count the character that have entered in the editor.I achieved this using the following code

```
    function removeHtmlTags(html)
    {
        var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
    }



var val = removeHtmlTags($(this).html());
var strLength = (val == 'undefined' || val ==  undefined) ? "0" : val.length;
```

and i displayed strLength as count.. but the problem I am facing here is while am saving the data into db the html tags also getting saved.. so the text am saving in db exceeds it maximum limit of storage.

for eg : if I have entered one word and I have used too many space and next line.. my counter will show only the length of the word..but in db it will save the word as well as the html tags for space and new line..

therefore I will get server side validation error the length of the text exceeded maximum limit.I can not change the db settings as it is live db

Please any one help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can anyone please help to me resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just show actual counter (content + tag). You didn't have to strip the tags before get the string length. Or you just get it like this: `$('#the-textarea').val().length`

n.b: honestly I wasn't sure what you try to accomplish, didn't have enough reputation to ask it in comment. I hope my guessed answer above meets your need :D